# Are fiberglass planters good for citrus trees?

Tags: trees, containers

I have ordered two 5-7 year old citrus trees(orange and lime). Now I am looking for sturdy enough planters to plant them in in my backyard. I am going for the look underneath. However if I get that made out of cement it would way around 800lbs for 31 inches in diameter. My floor is marble and it will likely crack under this pressure.

I see that there are fiberglass options that are a lot lighter. Will those be sturdy enough to contain the trees without breaking over the pressure of the roots.

I am also planting in planters because I don't want the trees to get really big.

[image]

Comment: Roots only produce "pressure" if there is nothing that can move out of the way (e.g. a root growing under a concrete slab). In a planter, the roots will just push the soil level up a bit as they grow.

Comment: If you are worried about cracking the floor, note that a 31 inch cube of dirt will weigh 1200 pounds (or more if it is wet) even without the weight of the container!

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research online and calling a few places the only way to go about a look like this that is not too heavy and is sturdy enough is to go with something made out of metal. Either steel(can get rusty) or aluminum. I found a company that makes planters for trees both from steel and aluminum and that is who I will go with.

Here's a [link](https://ore.design/) to their website. Be aware that if you decide to order from them you will need to place an order through a company, you can use your landscapers. This company told me they do not operate directly with individuals.